# Converting List<CompletableFuture<T>> to CompletableFuture<List<T>>

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have a method `doTransmit` which returns a `CompletableFuture<T>`. I want to call `doTransmit` in a loop and collect all the `CompletableFuture<T>` and convert into a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>` which resolves with the `List<T>` when all the collected `CompletableFuture<T>` have been resolved.

```
CompletableFuture<DeliveryResponse> doTransmit(Notification notification, Receiver receiver, ContentMutator contentMutator) {
   //send notification to this receiver
}

CompletableFuture<List<DeliveryResponse>> doTransmit(Notification notification, List<Receiver> receivers, ContentMutator contentMutator) {
        List<CompletableFuture<DeliveryResponse>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        receivers.forEach(receiver -> completableFutures.add(doTransmit(notification.clone(), receiver, contentMutator)));
        CompletableFuture<List<DeliveryResponse>> listCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(ArrayList::new);
        completableFutures.forEach(
                completableFuture ->
                        completableFuture.thenCombine(listCompletableFuture,
                            ((deliveryResponse, deliveryResponses) -> deliveryResponses.add(deliveryResponse))
                        )
        );
        return listCompletableFuture;
}
```

But when I call the second `doTransmit(notification, receivers, null).thenAccept(list -> System.out.println(list.size()));` the list received is empty.

I am new to the `CompletableFuture` concept. However, I know Javascript Promises. Please help.

Comment: So you want a `CompletableFuture` containing the `List` of the results of the other `CompletableFuture`s?

Comment: `List<CompletableFuture<T>>` to `List<T>` would make sense. I don't know why you'd want `CompletableFuture<List<T>>`... The `T`s will have already been calculated.

Comment: From ```List<DeliveryResponse>``` I can check how many notifications have been delivered or failed.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `Supplier<List<DeliveryResponse>>` which collects the responses:

```
// your code
List<CompletableFuture<DeliveryResponse>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
receivers.forEach(receiver -> completableFutures.add(doTransmit(notification.clone(), receiver, contentMutator)));

Supplier<List<DeliveryResponse>> responseCollector = () -> {
    List<DeliveryResponse> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // get the result for each... I think you need to try-catch this
    receivers.forEach(r -> result.add(r.get());
    return result;
}
```

and then create a `CompletableFuture` from that:

```
CompletableFuture<List<DeliveryResponse>> listFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(responseCollector);
return listFuture;
```

Now the `listFuture` collects the results by calling `get` for each of the futures.

Comment: In ```receivers.forEach(r -> result.add(r.get());``` ```r``` is not an instance of ```CompletableFuture```.